# How to get text and img from Listview to another activity using requestcode

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to get text and images from listview to few imageviews(buttons) and textviews that use request_code. At this moment I have error "java.lang.RuntimeException:Failure delivering resultResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=intent{(has extras)}} to activity...

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

final int REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER1 = 1;
final int REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER2 = 2;
int position;
String[] name;
int[] photo;
TextView playerName1;
TextView playerName2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playerName1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerName1);
    playerName2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerName2);
    btnPlayer1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPlayer1);
    btnPlayer2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPlayer2);
    btnPlayer1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlayer2.setOnClickListener(this);

    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgPlayer1:
            intent = new Intent(this, ListHeroes.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER1);
            break;
        case R.id.imgPlayer2:
            intent = new Intent(this, ListHeroes.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER2);
            break;
            default:
            break;
    }
}
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER1:
                position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");
                name = intent.getStringArrayExtra("name");
                photo = intent.getIntArrayExtra("photo");
                playerName1.setText(name[position]);
                btnPlayer1.setImageResource(photo[position]);
                break;

            case REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER2:
                position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");
                name = intent.getStringArrayExtra("name");
                photo = intent.getIntArrayExtra("photo");
                playerName2.setText(name[position]);
                btnPlayer2.setImageResource(photo[position]);
                break;

     }
     } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hero is not selected", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

   }
   }
```

ListHeroes Activity

```
public class ListHeroes extends Activity {

ListView list;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
String[] name;
int[] photo;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

name = new String[]{"kamen", "nozhnitsi", "bumaga"};
photo = new int[]{R.drawable.kamen, R.drawable.nozhnitsi, R.drawable.bumaga}

list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, name, photo);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Capture ListView item click
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.putExtra("name", name);

            intent.putExtra("photo", photo);

            intent.putExtra("position", position);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

        }

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Replace above code with following

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = data;
```